# Controller functions run twice with logged-in user?

Tags: laravel

I have a simple piece of code that keeps track of every time a specific route is called, but I notice that it somehow adds 2 visits whenever it's triggered instead of just 1. This is however only when the visitor is a logged in user, as a guest it works normally. Why?

The Page model containing the code for counting route requests.

```
class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * Find the correct page for the given route name or create a placeholder and increase visit count
     * 
     * @param string $name
     * @return App\Models\Page
     */
    public static function findOrNewAndCount($name)
    {
        $page = self::where('name', $name)->first();

        // If no Page can be found, create a new one for the given route.
        if ($page == null) {
            $page = new Page;
            $page->name = $name;
            $page->section = 'missing';
            $page->save();
        }

        // Increase visit_count by 1
        $page->visit_count = $page->visit_count + 1;
        $page->last_visit_at = now();
        $page->save();

        return $page;
    }
}
```

Using the function in a Controller

```
class AboutUsController extends Controller
{

     /** Show business details page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function details()
    {
        $page = Page::findOrNewAndCount('about_us.details');

        return view('about_us/details', compact('page'));
    }
}
```

The called route

```
Route::get('about_us/details', 'AboutUsController@details')->name('about_us.details');
```

What I really don't understand is why it even differs between logged in users and guests where there isn't any Middleware used for this route.

There is some User role&permission checking going on for the navigation bar but that shouldn't trigger this specific route to be called twice, right?

Comment: What if `$page` is empty? here `$page->visit_count = $page->visit_count + 1;` but if `$page` is empty then?

Comment: If `$page` empty, as in I haven't created a specific Page for the route yet, it creates a new one. The pages table has 
            `$table->integer('visit_count')->default(0);` so it starts with 0 and adds to that.